# How to use a list of categories that example belongs to as a feature solving classification problem?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

One of features looks like this:

```
1       170,169,205,174,173,246,247,249,380,377,383,38...
2       448,104,239,277,276,99,154,155,76,412,139,333,...
3       268,422,419,124,1,17,431,343,341,435,130,331,5...
4       50,53,449,106,279,420,161,74,123,364,231,18,23...
5       170,169,205,174,173,246,247,249,380,377,383,38...
```

It tells us what categories the example belongs to.
How should I use it while solving classification problem?

I've tried to use dummy variables,

```
df=df.join(features['cat'].str.get_dummies(',').add_prefix('contains_'))
```

but we don't know where there are some other categories that were not mentioned in the training set, so, I do not know how to preprocess all the objects.

Comment: what do you want to tell us?

Comment: @PV8: that's the old problem of ML and dummy-columns. If you trained a model on a specific column layout, you need to apply the same column layout later during the production phase. Your model doesn't want to see columns which were not present during training and likewise it doesn't like it if columns disappear because the data that caused the columns to be generated is not present anymore.

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting. I didn't know `str.get_dummies`, but maybe I can help you with the rest.

You basically have two problems:

1. The set of categories you get later contains categories that were unknown while training the model. You have to get rid of these later.
2. The set of categories you get later does not contain all categories. You have to make sure, you generate dummies for them as well.

## Problem 1: filtering out unknown/unwanted categories

The first problem is easy to solve:

```
# create a set of all categories, you want to allow
# either definie it as a fixed set, or extract it from your
# column like this (the output of the map is actually irrelevant)
# the result will be in valid_categories
valid_categories= set()
df['categories'].str.split(',').map(valid_categories.update)

# now if you want to normalize your data before you do the
# dummy encoding, you can cleanse the data by
# splitting it, creating an intersection and then joining
# it back again to get a string on which you can work with
# str.get_dummies
df['categories'].str.split(',').map(lambda l: valid_categories.intersection(l)).str.join(',')
```

## Problem 2: generating dummies for all known categories

The second problem can be solved by just adding a dummy row, that
contains all categories e.g. with `df.append` just before you
call `get_dummies` and removing it right after `get_dummies`.

```
# e.g. you can do it like this
# get a new index value to
# be able to remove the row later
# (this only works if you have
# a numeric index)
dummy_index= df.index.max()+1

# assign the categories
# 
df.loc[dummy_index]= {'id':999, 'categories': ','.join(valid_categories)}
# now do the processing steps 
# mentioned in the section above
# then create the dummies
# after that remove the dummy line
# again
df.drop(labels=[dummy_index], inplace=True)
```

Example:

```
import io

raw= """id      categories
1       170,169,205,174,173,246,247
2       448,104,239,277,276,99,154
3       268,422,419,124,1,17,431,343
4       50,53,449,106,279,420,161,74
5       170,169,205,174,173,246,247"""
df= pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(raw))

valid_categories= set()
df['categories'].str.split(',').map(valid_categories.update)
# remove 154 and 170 for demonstration purposes
valid_categories.remove('170')
valid_categories.remove('154')

df['categories'].str.split(',').map(lambda l: valid_categories.intersection(l)).str.join(',').str.get_dummies(',')
Out[622]: 
   1  104  106  124  161  169  17  173  174  205  239  246  247  268  276  277  279  343  419  420  422  431  448  449  50  53  74  99
0  0    0    0    0    0    1   0    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0
1  0    1    0    0    0    0   0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0   0   0   0   1
2  1    0    0    1    0    0   1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    0   0   0   0   0
3  0    0    1    0    1    0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1   1   1   1   0
4  0    0    0    0    0    1   0    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0
```

You can see, that there are not columns for 154 and 170.